# Why my loop is returning 0 instead of looped value?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get `rownumber` from an array from a text file. So that I can replace the strings and rewrite the file. After a few tries, the code does not have errors but not working. When I try to validate the error, I set a label to be the returned value to see if it's returning anything. Turns out it just shows zero. Which I'm confident that something is wrong with my return loops.

account.txt

```
seow 1111 wen 12345 20 50  
user 1234 user1 12345 70 80
```

code

```
        private string[] filelist;
        public string[] Filelist
        { get { return filelist; } }

        private static readonly int LineNo = 1000;

        public int GetRowNumber()
        {
            string username = login.accountname;
            TextReader sr = new StreamReader("account.txt");
            bool found = false;
            int i = 0;
            while(i < LineNo && !found)
            {
                filelist[i] = sr.ReadLine();
                if (filelist.Contains(username))
                    found = true;
                else i++;
            }
            if(found==true)
            {
                row= i;

                sr.Close();
            }

            return row;

        }
```

it should show the row number when the butten is clicked.

```
 private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           row = GetRowNumber();
           label12.Text = row;
        }
```

Not returning any row value in the array, but just return a zero value

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Where do you declare the _LineNo_ variable and how do you initialize it? If its value is zero then no loop is executed and you get the default value for _row_ (another unknown variable)

Comment: Please provide a sample of "account.txt" with randomized data please

Comment: @Steve LineNo variable is declared as private static int readonly LineNo = 1000;

Comment: Please produce and post an [MRE] so we can help you. If `row` is 0, then either you're seeing the default value, or the row found is in fact 0.

Comment: Then I think that the only way to discover what's happening here is to debug your program as suggested in the first comment here

Comment: ive updated stuffs that should be included

Comment: it is just the username from the login form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is inside the loop.
This line will never work

```
 if (filelist.Contains(username))
```

if your input is *"Seow"* and the array contains *"seow 1111 wen 12345 20 50"*
Contains called on a string array will check every entry for an exact match to your input and of course you don't have an exact match.
But the fix is pretty simple here

```
filelist[i] = sr.ReadLine();
if (filelist[i].Contains(username))
```

Now we call Contains on a string and this will be a partial match and thus the line will be found

Comment: wow i cant believe its just a simple error that i didnt notice, thanks alot it works now